# Are these Helsinki Incidents the same?

Tags: orphan-black, morgan

In the 2016 movie, *Morgan*, there is discussion of the "Helsinki Incident"; Lee Weathers (Kate Mara), the risk management consultant, says that she was there "after", not during the situation.

There is also a ["Helsinki Incident" in the history of Orphan Black](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89718/which-clones-were-involved-in-the-helsinki-incident).  The background, of a corporation which is playing God, is similar.  Is there any indication that these events were, or were intended to be, the same?

Answer (score 2):

### No.

There is no evidence that they are in the same universe or referring to the same thing.

[Helsinki is the capital of Finland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki), so literally anything that happens there can get the name "Helsinki Incident".

*Orphan Black* was made by BBC America. *Morgan* was released by 20th Century Fox. While that doesn't rule it out, it is another nail in the coffin.